# Load Wikipedia page on my website

Tags: php, facebook, wikipedia-api

How can I add Wikipedia result as text in my website, Just like facebook has done.

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Lyon-France/108560402508141
```

Is there any good libraries that I can use?
I am doing my website in php. Downloading the entire content and showing it will take more time. Any other solution?

Comment: Yes, use the wikipeadia api: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: This looks like an extensive and potentially helpful walkthrough for what you're looking to do: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpwikipedia/. You basically should search for the combination of "wikipedia php" and at least one of library, api.

Comment: @codejak  Thanks for the reply. Let me try this. It may help.. Thank u all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an extensive and potentially helpful walkthrough for what you're looking to do: [ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpwikipedia](http://ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpwikipedia).

You basically should search for the combination of "wikipedia php" and at least one of [library, api].

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a possibility to do this. You can use PHP cURL to achieve this. You have to activate cURL in your php.ini file to be able to use it. You can read all about cURL on php.net

[Curl manual php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)